# Understanding bool operator==(paramater 1, parameter 2)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

`bool operator==(str_array a, str_array b)`

Where `str_array` is a struct for my assignment. What does this notation mean, how will this need to be considered for when I implement the function, and how do I call it when I'm done (same as normal function calls?)

This is the first time seeing this notation. The implementation is a simple comparison between two `str_array` variables (I know how to implement this without the weird notation)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I call it when I'm done?

As you have defined an *operator*, then it is *not* called like a 'normal' function! Rather, it can be used like a 'normal' operator:

```cpp
str_array sa1;
str_array sa2;
//.. some code
if (sa1 == sa2) { // Here, you are calling the == OPERATOR that you've defined
    //.. do something
}
```

The **implementation** will, however, *look like* a normal function:

```cpp
bool operator==(str_array a, str_array b) {
    bool answer;
    //..
    // some code that sets "answer" according to the (in)equality of a and b
    //
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like (where a and b are str_array)

```
if (a == b) { // ...
```

This function will be called.

`operator==` is the name of the function that using the `==` calls. You are supposed to return true if the arguments are equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is **operator overloading**. You are creating an overload of the `==` operator that accepts an `str_array` object on either side of the operator:

```
str_array a1;
str_array a2;
...
if (a1 == a2)
    do_something();
```

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
bool operator==(str_array a, str_array b);
```

introduces an overloaded equality operator (operator ==) for objects of the type `str_array`.

So you can compare twp objects of the type as you do with fundamental types as for example

```
if ( a == b ) { /* do something */ }
```

The compiler will substitute the expression `a == b` for a call of the overloaded `operator ==` (function).

Here is a demonstrative program with two overloaded operators: `operator ==` and `operator <<`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}

    friend bool operator ==( const A &a1, const A &a2 )
    {
        return a1.x == a2.x;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A &a )
    {
        return os << a.x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main() 
{
    A a1( 10 ), a2( 10 ), a3( 20 );

    std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2 = " << a2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "a3 = " << a3 << '\n';

    std::cout << "a1 == a2 is " << std::boolalpha << ( a1 == a2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2 == a3 is " << std::boolalpha << ( a2 == a3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "a1 == a2 is " << std::boolalpha << operator ==( a1, a2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
a1 = 10
a2 = 10
a3 = 20
a1 == a2 is true
a2 == a3 is false
a1 == a2 is true
```